# Batch file to add words to strings in a txt file

Tags: batch-file

Iv'e got a txt file that has words in it, all in one column,
and I wanted to create a batch file that puts "Send " before the word and "{Enter}" after the word (without the quotes).
So say I have in the txt file:

```
cow
monkey
cat
```

I want it to become:

```
Send cow{Enter}

Send monkey{Enter}

Send cat{Enter}
```

Thanks.

Ok so now I want to do some more  things.

So I have:

```
Send cat{Enter}
Send cow{Enter}
```

I want to make it so the whole file looks like this:

```
!z::
loop
{

Send cow{Enter}

Send cat{Enter}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read each line of your file, create your sentence and append it to a new file, something like :

```
for /f %%i in (c:\temp\test.txt) do echo send %%i {enter} >> c:\temp\test2.txt
```

after your edit :

```
echo !z:: > c:\temp\test2.txt
echo loop >> c:\temp\test2.txt
echo { >> c:\temp\test2.txt

for /f %%i in (c:\temp\test.txt) do echo send %%i {enter} >> c:\temp\test2.txt

echo }>> c:\temp\test2.txt
```

Comment: wow, it worked. thank you so much. yeah i knew it had something to do with the for command. ok so now I have this list, i want to some other stuff the the file too.

Comment: Got it all working now thank you. just using it to automatically write an ahk script.

Comment: @JustBlu instead of adding a comment to thanks someone on SO, you should accept or upvote its answer.